# How to punctuate the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence

The sentence:

> Set in Italy and England, the story is both a romance and a critique
>   of English society at the beginning of the 20th century.

It is from `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Room_with_a_View`.

I am not sure `a romance` should be interpreted alone or with `of English society`

1. If interpreted alone, 'romance' means 'a story that deals with
   sexual love'
2. Or 'a romance of English society' means the "a mysterious or
   fascinating quality of the English society"

I prefer the second interpretation.

Comment: You can talk about a *critique of X*, but idiomatically, a *romance of X* doesn't work, so grammatically you shouldn't assume a connection between *romance* and *English society*. Anyway, it's quite possible all the romance takes place in Italy (they are famous for that sort of thing, obviously! :)

Comment: The `both...and..` structure confuses me. I thought `romance` and `critique` are counterparts.

Comment: Well, there must be scope for ambiguity in this construction if we use different words for *This is both an **X** and a **Y** of **Z***. Offhand I can't think of any substitutions where "unqualified" *an X* could reasonably be understood to mean something different to *an X of Y* in such a context, but maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is correctly punctuated.

To expand, since "romance of English society" makes little sense, the intent of the author is reasonably clear. The sentence could be rewritten so it is easier to read, but not such that it would be clearer to a native speaker.

Comment: Yeah, certain P-ists would require a comma after "romance", but said comma would neither further clarify the sentence nor make it easier to read.